# Hiding first-child, second child tags for selected <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Apologies, the title may be a bit confusing.

I have multiple `<div>`' which generate automatically.

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner  selected">
    <div class="checkbox-row">
      <span class="fakelabel">
        <input id="id_300622" type="checkbox" name="id_300622" checked="checked">
        <span>Marketing</span>
        <span>Email</span> <span> | </span>
        <span>Blog | Subscription</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>Receive timely updates with the latest blog posts.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner  selected">
    <div class="checkbox-row">
      <span class="fakelabel">
        <input id="id_4849126" type="checkbox" name="id_4849126" checked="checked">
        <span>Careers Subscription</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>Receive timely updates with the latest blog posts.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I the snippet above, I want the first three `span` to be `display:none;`, so it only shows the `<span>Blog | Subscription</span>`tag.

I can implement the following to hide the tags:

```
.fakelabel span:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

However, doing the above would also hide the "Careers Subscription" text in the second div.

Ideally, I want the last `<span>` to always be visible in each div, and hide any other ones. But I'm not sure how to approach this?

**Note**: I cannot alter the HTML since the HTML code is generated automatically via HubSpot (a pain!). Is this possible through JavaScript/CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally, I want the last `<span>` to always be visible in each div, and hide any other ones. But I'm not sure how to approach this?

Use the `:not` syntax and the `last-of-type` selector.

```css
.fakelabel span:not(:last-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner  selected">
    <div class="checkbox-row">
      <span class="fakelabel">
        <input id="id_300622" type="checkbox" name="id_300622" checked="checked">
        <span>Marketing</span>
      <span>Email</span> <span> | </span>
      <span>Blog | Subscription</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>Receive timely updates with the latest blog posts.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner  selected">
    <div class="checkbox-row">
      <span class="fakelabel">
        <input id="id_4849126" type="checkbox" name="id_4849126" checked="checked">
        <span>Careers Subscription</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>Receive timely updates with the latest blog posts.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```